# cUrl can't access to file but browser does

Tags: php, curl

I want to get file contents (without file_get_contents function) via cUrl but I can't open it with cUrl

My link is [here](http://panel.1n3k.com/6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca/api/media/4/logo/831710_1464331440.png)

I tested my hosting with requestb.in and results are [here](https://requestb.in/z8fqakz8?inspect)

```
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip';
$header[] = 'Connection: close';
$header[] = 'Host: panel.1n3k.com';
$header[] = 'User-Agent: runscope-radar/2.0';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
curl_close($ch);
```

I tried with agent `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` with my browser's agent.

`CURLOPT_REFERER`, `CURLOPT_ENCODING`, `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER`

one by one but no one could help me...

How this can be posible ?

Comment: Impossible to tell without more information, could be a server-side redirect, javascript, etc.

Comment: I'm using htaccess on panel.1n3k.com too but i can access via browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one to view your link image contents

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

$url = 'http://panel.1n3k.com/6512bd43d9caa6e02c990b0a82652dca/api/media/4/logo/831710_1464331440.png';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.1 Safari/537.11');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$rescode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch) ;
echo $res;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Awais, it doesnt solved my problem but i found the solution. It's the server's fault. When I try your code (or my code) on localhost it's working but 1n3k.com and the domain which i try to call are on same server. So, it's the matter of DNS or something like that. Thanks for at least forcing me to try on localhost :)